# Kotlin Dagger 2 Sharing ViewModel between Activity and Fragment

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, code-injection, dagger

As mentioned in the title I've got a problem with Dagger 2 injection. I have a single activity and multiple fragments. I'm trying to share activity's ViewModel with every child fragment. I based my solution on Google's Android Architecture ToDo sample. I've created ViewModelFactory as

[ViewModelFactory](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dagger-android/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/di/ViewModelFactory.kt)

If you jump to the link you will see that in their solution there's a separate ViewModel for every activity and fragment. They are not showing how to deal with scenarios like mine. My implementation of ActivityModule looks like:

```
 @Module
 abstract class SampleModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
            modules = [
                ViewModelBuilder::class
            ]
    )
    internal abstract fun sampleActivity(): SampleActivity

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SampleViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindViewModel(viewModel: SampleViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

My activity extends `DaggerAppCompatActivity` and fragment `DaggerFragment` and as follows my injection of view model looks simple as

```
class SampleActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

   @Inject
   lateinit var viewModel: SampleViewModel
   ...
```

I can't find a web solution to my problem. I'm a pretty novice user of Dagger. I've tried to implement Subcomponent but still, it's not working because all the examples I have searched so far didn't use `DaggerApplication`, `DaggerAppCompatActivity` and my way of injection. Please suggest any solution or if a subcomponent way is right please show me how to do it if it's possible in my current architecture.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your explanation is less, What exactly the error is? post your ``trace`` if there is exception, and did you add _SampleModule_ in _Component_ ? and if you are using _daggerApplication_ did u enable it from _manifest_ file? and your dependency graph and object graph are all set properly?

Answer (score 1):

@silaros88 I was facing yor same issue, **share a ViewModel between multiple fragmnets in a single Activity application**, and i solved playing with the `ViewmModelStoreOwner`.

Steps to fix your issue.

- See here [TasksFragment.kt](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/98d204da274909002c97cd9f88248dc8dc92acd0/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksFragment.kt#L49) how they inject the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` instead of the `ViewModel`
- Retrieve the desire ViewModel using one of this two options:

  - `viewModels<SharedDesireViewModel> (requireActivity()) { Injected ViewModelProvider.Factory }`
  - `ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), Injected ViewModelProvider.Factory ).get(SharedDesireViewModel::class.java)`

**Examples:**

**Option #1:**

**FragmentA.kt**

```
class FragmentA: DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelProviderFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels({requireActivity()}) { viewModelProviderFactory }

    ......
```

**FragmentB.kt**

```
class FragmentB: DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelProviderFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels({requireActivity()}) { viewModelProviderFactory }

    ......
```

**Option #2:**

**FragmentA.kt**

```
class FragmentA: DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelProviderFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), viewModelProviderFactory)
        .get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }

    ......
```

**FragmentB.kt**

```
class FragmentB: DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelProviderFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), viewModelProviderFactory)
        .get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }

    ......
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a slightly different approach.
Since the fragments and the activity both have dagger modules.
In the ActivityModule I am providing the sharedViemodel as below

```
@Module
class ActivityModule(private val activity: AppCompatActivity) 
{

  @Provides
  fun provideMainSharedVieModel() : MainSharedViewModel = 
     ViewModelProvider(activity).get(MainSharedViewModel::class.java)
 }
```

And in my fragment module I am again providing the same viemodel as below:

```
@Module
class FragmentModule(private val fragment: Fragment) 
{

  @Provides
  fun provideMainSharedVieModel() : MainSharedViewModel = 
     ViewModelProvider(fragment.activity!!).get(MainSharedViewModel::class.java)
 }
```

Since the ViewModels are stored in a map with the activity or fragments as the key, hence providing the sharedViewModel with "fragment.activity!!" in the Fragment module will not create a new instance of the viewmodel , it will just the return the already instantiated shared viewmodel to the fragment.